# Mathematical Functions in p5.js

Tags: javascript, function, math, graph, p5.js

I'm trying to imitate what other graphing function applications do, as practice in p5.js. But I can't have a textbox that returns the function inside the codes, like when I write

```js
pow(x,2)
```

in the codes, codes recognized it as `string`, note that `x` is defined inside the codes.
 Does anyone know how can I fix this? I just want to focus in `p5.js`.

All of my work is done, it's just that there is no interaction through a textbox. Thank you for your response, I'm sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: can you share more html and js code?

Comment: @db1975 what do u mean,  by the way, this is the site https://p5js.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow storing a string to your variable x. Without more context we cannot help you effectively.

One thing you could do is replace pow(x,2) with pow(***parseInt(x)***,2), but this is assuming that the string is continaing the number you would like to use.